# PHP/SQL - Reading Text File If a line is equal to database value echo username?

Tags: php, sql

I have a text file file over 10k lines of random names (names.txt), and a Database containing user information (user_info)

The user_info database is structured similar to this:

```
user_id, name,           email,             DoB,           gender

   1,    John,           email@email.com,   01/01/1990       M
   2,    Tim,            email2@email.com,   01/01/1991       M
```

And so on..

What I'm basically trying to achieve is a name search using a txt document.

so when you upload the text document if a a name in there is 'Tim' it'll echo all the users called Tim in the user_info database along with their email, Date of Birth and gender.

(I have no Idea how to do this but I'm guessing something like this)

```
<form action="search.php" method="post" >
                         <input type="hidden" name = "submit" value="Search" />
                </form>


 <?php

 $namestxt = file("/names.txt");

     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{


      $getUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `name` = '".$namestxt."'");

  while ($userInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUsers))
  {

   echo $userInfo['name'].' . $userInfo['email'] . $userInfo['DoB']  . $userInfo['gender']<br/>';

  }


}


  ?>
```

I know this code is probably way off, but hopefully you can understand what I am trying to do here.

Any help, thanks.

Comment: in what structure is the text file written? CSV? or just randomly

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Just randomly seperated by [enter] I could easily convert to CSV though if it would make it easier

Answer (score 0):

`$namestxt` is an array of strings read from your file. 
You can address elements by index: `$namestxt[0]` (first line in file).
Or iterate them with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). 
You could then compose a SQL query `select * from user_info where name in('Name1','Name2')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$getUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info;");

while($userInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUsers))
{
    if(in_array($userInfo['name'], $namestxt))
    {
        echo $userInfo['name'] . ' ' . $userInfo['email'] . ' ' . $userInfo['DoB'] . ' ' . $userInfo['gender'] . '<br />';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'user not found';
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error when trying this also: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: Same error again, on line 21: while($userInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUsers))      thanks for your help

Comment: could it be the missing semicolon at the end of the query?

Comment: It was my config sorry, this nearly works but when testing it echos both user not found and the results

Comment: ah sorry I think it's the quotes around `user_info`, copy and paste my edit

Comment: it echoes user not found because it is cycling through every user in the text file. change the `else` statement to `continue;` if you want nothing to be displayed when a user is not found, or better still just delete the `else` altogether :)

Comment: For some reason, It is now not finding any info at all, In the text document for testing I have just put two names, John and Tim and in the DB i have 2 names, John and Craig. It's doing right in not finding Tim but it also doesn't find John

Comment: hmmn, maybe a case-sensitivity issue, do the cases match in the text file and the DB?

Comment: In the text file is there a space character after John or anything?

Comment: I think the issue is that there is no seperation because when i change it back to 'not found' instead of continue; it prints 'not foundnot found' without any space between, and when I test with one name it works successfully. If i change the file to CSV comma delimited is it possible to work around this?

Comment: 'not foundnot found' is because there is no space in the PHP. if you were to edit to: `echo 'user not found ';` with the space then there would be one. changing to CSV would make no difference, you'd still end up with an array of names to compare, the only difference being the method of `explode()`ing as opposed to `file()`. not sure what the problem could be but post back once you solve it :) I'm stumped for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that $snamestext, which is currently an array, into a comma separated string so you can use 'IN' in the query.

```
 $namestext = implode("'", $namestext);

 ......

 $getUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `name` IN ('$namestxt')");
```

Also while echoing out the results you probably want to organize them in a table and check if that text file even exists before starting the process.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I try this I get this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource